# Debugging WordPress Cron Job Issues

Tags: wordpress, plugins, cron

I'm currently trying to make a cron event on my WordPress website that automatically updates a .txt file to include all the usernames that have an active subscription on the Paid Memberships Pro plugin. The cron file does update my file, but it display the debug message I've added. I'm 100% sure I have people with an active subscription and I'm a bit stuck at this point.

I hope someone has a solution for this, thanks!

```
$plan_ids = array(2, 3, 4);
$users = get_users( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'pmpro_membership_level',
            'value'   => $plan_ids,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'pmpro_expiration_date',
            'value'   => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
            'compare' => '>',
            'type'    => 'DATETIME'
        )
    )
) );

$usernames = array();
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $usernames[] = '"' . $user->user_login . '"';
}

$file_path = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/2023/04/usernames.txt';
$file_content = ! empty( $usernames ) ? implode( ", ", $usernames ) . "\n" : "No users with an active Paid Memberships Pro plan matching the criteria found.\n";
file_put_contents( $file_path, $file_content, FILE_APPEND );

// Debug code
if ( empty( $users ) ) {
    error_log( 'No users with an active Paid Memberships Pro plan matching the criteria found.' );
} else {
    $membership_levels = array();
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $membership_levels[] = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'pmpro_membership_level', true );
    }
    error_log( count( $users ) . ' users with active Paid Memberships Pro plans found. Membership levels: ' . implode( ', ', $membership_levels ) );
}
```

I've tried adding the experation date checking, but that didn't do anything.